# How to cast DB2 Timestamp to vb.net date?

Tags: vb.net, date, parsing, db2, format

When I populate my vb.net gridview using DB2 SQL, it displays DB2 Timestamp as:

```
2020-08-25-14.59.11.000000
```

^ What's the cleanest way to cast that as a vb.net Date? FWIW, this works:

```
Dim mydate As Date = CDate("2020-08-25 14:59:11.000000")
```

But, the colons in `14:59:11` do not exist, the string I'm working with has `14.59.11`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit:
As requested,
[screenshot of what data looks like when queried in AS400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYz2J.png)

Edit2:

```
Dim strSelect As String = "" &
"SELECT SUBMITTIME " &
"FROM MYTABLE " &
"WHERE EFYEAR=" & Now.Year & " AND EFMONTH=" & Now.Month

Dim dt As DataTable = SQL.Get_DataTable(strSelect)
grv.DataSource = dt
grv.DataBind()
```

Get_DataTable is just using OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, OleDbDataAdapter, etc to fill a DataTable.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your DB2 query tool having selected the same row

Comment: @CaiusJard just added

Comment: Is VB selecting it as a string? Show the code that fills the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast something as a type that it isn't. The whole point of casting is that you don't change the object but rather the way you access the object. If you're changing the object then it is a conversion, not a cast.

If you want to convert something then the first step is to know what you're converting from. If you are converting from a `String` of a known format to a `DateTime` then you would use `Date.ParseExact`.

If the data is in a `DataTable`, add a new column with the appropriate data type, do the conversion in a loop and then, if appropriate, remove the original column.

```vb
myDataTable.Columns.Add("DataColumn", GetType(Date))

For Each row As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
    row("DateColumn") = Date.ParseExact(CStr(row("TextColumn")), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff", Nothing)
Next

myDataTable.Columns.Remove(myDataTable.Columns("TextColumn"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. The DataTable loop may come in handy soon, this is what I'm using to display:

`<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblSUBMITTIME" runat="server" Text='<%# Date.ParseExact(Eval("SUBMITTIME"), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff", Nothing) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>`